# Selectively turning off Eclipse formatting of XML files

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatting

There is a way to turn off Eclipse formatting(of Java code) selectively (see [here](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part2.html#JavaFormatter)).

Is there a equivalent for formatting of XML files?

Comment: Can you clarify?  Are you asking two different questions?

Comment: Bug filed with a feature request in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=574701

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The only thing you can do is to select "Preserve whitespace in tags with PCDATA Content"

Comment: Please see the CDATA trick in the answer from @sgrillon.  I don't think this should be the accepted answer, but I'm not downvoting.

Answer (score 5):

`<token><![CDATA[..... Your line ....]]></token>`

On Eclispe, I use this solution in a pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
    <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
    <unescape>true</unescape>
    <includes>
        <include>src/test/resources/steps/scenarios/xxxxxx.feature</include>
    </includes>
    <token><![CDATA[Then home page is displayed[\\s\\S]*Then go to PRODUCTION]]></token>
    <value><![CDATA[Then home page is displayed\n\n    ##patch for IC\n    Then I change CP\n    ##end patch for IC\n\n    Then go to PRODUCTION]]></value>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The CDATA trick worked well to prevent the Eclipse XML formatter from breaking a long Docker cmd/shell value into pieces that then fail, thx.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to set this up but if you are after  some sort of predefined consistency you could use the *Design* tab of the XML file, opened with the *XML Editor* to add/edit tags.